# Как устанвоить расширение CITEXT в postgres на ubuntu

Tags: sql, postgresql, расширения

Вот небольшая часть схемы, где я пытаюсь установить и использовать CITEXT. К сожалению postgres не видит расширение и пишет `ERROR: type "citext" does not exist`. Что с этим делать?

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS forum CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA forum;

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS CITEXT SCHEMA forum;


CREATE TABLE forum.profile
(
    nickname CITEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    fullname VARCHAR(60)             NOT NULL,
    about    TEXT                    NOT NULL,
    email    VARCHAR(60) UNIQUE      NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: покажите свой search_path

Comment: @Мелкий, что это _)

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя пользоваться схемами и не знать, что такое [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH)

Вы можете при обращении к чему-либо не указывать имя схемы, если эта схема входит в ваш search_path. В search_path в значении по умолчанию входят схема, имя которой совпадает с именем пользователя, схемы public, pg_catalog, pg_temp этой сессии. В остальных случаях вы должны указывать имя схемы.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS CITEXT SCHEMA forum;
```

Здесь вы попросили установить расширение в схему forum. Туда всё это расширение и было поставлено. Почему вы решили следом обращаться с запросом по созданию таблицы `forum.profile`, но тип данных указать лишь только CITEXT вместо `forum.citext`?

Типы text и varchar на самом деле в схеме pg_catalog, потому видимы. Схема forum в вашем search_path отсутствует - потому такого типа данных найти не удалось.